How do I run Wayland in Ubuntu 24.10?
I usually run xfce4 and Openbox.  After installing Ubuntu 24.10, I thought I'd try out Wayland.  So in the login screen, and choose xfce + wayland from the tool menu, then login.  After a couple seconds I'm kicked back into the login screen.
Same thing happens when I try gnome + wayland and gnome classic + wayland.
Does this mean Wayland isn't fully installed on my system?  How would I check?  Running apt search wayland I get
wayland-protocols/oracular,oracular,now 1.36-1 all [installed,automatic]
wayland-utils/oracular,now 1.2.0-1build1 amd64 [installed]
weston/oracular,now 13.0.3-1 amd64 [installed]
xwayland/oracular-updates,oracular-security,now 2:24.1.2-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Not sure what else I might need.
Another odd thing is that after unsuccessfully trying to start a Wayland session, I then start my normal xfce + openbox session, but firefox and telegram run terribly slowly.  I have to reboot the system to get everything back to normal.
Any suggestions on what I might try?

XFCE has poor wayland support. If you want to use gnome+wayland, install ubuntu-desktop package (or use a clutter-free fresh installation), and it should work without these issues

I installed ubuntu-desktop, and no change for "ubuntu + wayland", but now "gnome + wayland" give me a green screen of death.  Is that progress?

https://thelinuxcode.com/enable-disable-wayland-ubuntu/   ... does this link help?

Thanks but no, I've already tried selecting gnome + wayland
